# Java applet scale

Tags: java, canvas, applet, resize, jframe

I have a java game that I have made, is it a Canvas in a JFrame to run as an application and an applet.

When running as an applet, I want it so that when the user resizes the window, the game scales to fit the new size window.

Is there anyway of resizing the canvas and all the images or shapes that I have drawn on it to fit the new size window, or do I have to go though and change the code on all my objects and the positions they draw?

Any help would be very useful :)

Comment: @Humphrey Shotton: "Canvas in a JFrame"  Don't mix Swing components with AWT.

Comment: @Andrew, with newer versions of Java 6, mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight components is not an issue.  Is it still a big issue to mix them?

Comment: @jzd:  If you knew what you were doing, AWT & Swing could be mixed all along (to a limited extent).  But ultimately, what can a `Canvas` do that a `JComponent` or `JPanel` could not?  Most people that mix Swing & AWT do it out of ignorance of the pitfalls *or* the alternatives.  If someone started their post with "I'm using the new functionality to mix an AWT style (..I like this component..) with a mainly Swing GUI.." I would not make comment.

Comment: @Andrew, I see your point.  That makes sense.

Comment: @Andrew: Should I change the JFrame to Canvas then or change my Canvas to a JFrame? I didn't realise I had done this and that there was this difference.

Comment: `JFrame` is not interchangeable with `Canvas`.   What is interchangeable is `JFrame`<->`Frame` & `JPanel` or `JComponent` <-> `Canvas`.  So if doing it as AWT, you'd use `Frame` with `Canvas`, but to do it using Swing, use `JFrame` with `JComponent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to add scaling to your painting.  A transformation applied to your graphics might be the easiest way.  You would determine the current size of the Canvas and scale based on the standard size.

Comment: Thanks for the info - does that mean that is the only way to do it?

Comment: @Humphrey, I am sure there is another way, but it would require modifying your painting to factor in a scale.

Comment: It is a huge hack, & would also probably result in a crappy and illogical display - but if the entire game is being rendered to a `BufferedImage`, then the width/height arguments of `Graphics.drawImage(x,y,width,height,ImageObserver)` can be used to stretch the image across the entire rendering surface.  But for the purposes of the game, I strongly recommend you ignore that comment & *use the strategy outlined by jzd.*